# other ways to use style-loader without bundling style-loader lib into every bundled style?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I was using webpack 5 to bundle my css styles, I wanted to include each module as is. without building it into a single file but I noticed that styles that were less than 1kb or even 5kb to 10kb are all above 30kb when I use style-loader.

I am assuming that is because of the style-loader code to inject the css into the body. I tried to use mini css extract but adding the css as link tags were not working for SPFX. so I ended up bundling it with file loader so it is a string and using a custom script to inject the styles.

```
export const attrReducer = (acc, cv) => cv[1] !== null || typeof cv[1] !== 'undefined'
  ? acc.concat(`${cv[0]}="${cv[1]}" `)
  : acc

export const mapToAttr = (o) => Object.entries(o).reduce(attrReducer, ``)

export const makeStyleTagLinkString = (props) => `<link ${mapToAttr(props)}></link>`
export const makeStyleTagString = ({ content, ...props }) => `<style ${mapToAttr(props)}>${content}</style>`

export const injectStyleTag = (props) => (url) => (
  !document.querySelector(`style[data-href="${url}"]`)
    ? document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', makeStyleTagString({ props, href: url }))
    : null
);
export const injectStyleLinkTag = (props) => (url) => (content) => (
  !document.querySelector(`style[data-href="${url}"]`)
    ? document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', makeStyleTagLinkString({ ...props, content: content }))
    : null
);
```

The above works well for my setup but this is really not what I wanted to ended up using, since webpack supposed to handle that for me.

Another issue is that style-loader was doing well for me, besides the problem of increasing the size of every css module, was to manipulate the style tag at build time depending on the content of the styles, this was useful for me cause I can apply the container query polyfill (or any other) based on the content of the css. ex:

```
{
  loader: "style-loader",
  options: {
    styleTagTransform: function (css, style) {
      css.indexOf('@container') > -1
        ? style.setAttribute('cqfill', '')
        : null;
      style.innerHTML = css;
      document.head.appendChild(style);
    },
  },
},
```

SPFX does have its own implementation for loading styles which I tried but it did not work well with the container-query-polyfill. Also no options to add anything to style tag or manipulate it in anyways.

```
export default class JQueryAccordionWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IJQueryAccordionWebPartProps> {
  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css');
    return super.onInit();
  }

  // ...
}
```

So the question is if there are other ways to export the css file as an assets and use either style loader as a separated lib to build the style or link tag?
Or any other library that I can include that does this without having to use custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand all parts of the question. With the `style-loader` and `mini-css-extract-plugin` it's important to know that in development mode the styles will always be injected from a JS file as that's faster. Only in a production build will the styles end up in a separate CSS file (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production').

Comment: That did not really work. As I am aware and I did not find any information supporting what you are saying. For the tests I have done even if I set it to production the style-loader code goes into the js bundle for every file emitted, plus just changing the "injectType" to 'linkTag' alone does nothing other than just putting the style content in the href attribute, which is weird I know, but this is what happens. So either I am missing something or if you know you can point me to an example of this working.

Comment: @RicardoSilva You're right, I'm remembering this wrong. Actually, the switch between the mini-css-extract-plugin and the style-loader has to be done manually. Here is the [documentation with an example](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#recommend) of how to do that. Need to correct this in my setup as well now ;)

Comment: mini-css-extract-plugin does not work for me for one of the setups which was spfx, the polyfill did not work with it. Which obviously is not an issue with mini-css-extract-plugin but I am trying to find other ways to bundle with style-loader which perfectly fit my needs the only thing is that I even if the css file is a js module it has to be just a exported string not a full module with 30kb of style-loader in it. which I already did, but using custom code is not something I wanted to do for that.